# Java: Windows 7 look-and-feel (or MouseListener?) requires clicking twice on JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane, look-and-feel

I have a simple app with a menu bar. On the menu bar is a button (JMenu) to open a file.

Clicking this button opens a JOptionPane with an input field, and buttons "OK" and "Cancel".

However, you need to click at least once on the JOptionPane to interact (with the mouse) with any component (the buttons or the input field). Meaning that if you enter the path, you have to click twice on the "OK" button.

I think it is a focus problem, however keyboard input works fine.

What's strange is that the default UI look-and-feel doesn't cause this bug, but my JOptionPane worked fine before (and I had the system UI look-and-feel, as well as the MouseListener), so I honestly don't know at all what causes this bug.

Code is here:

```
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class Classe1 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    JFrame jf = new JFrame();

    //Commenting this line makes it behave correctly
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());

    jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jf.setSize(new Dimension(400, 200));
    jf.setVisible(true);
    jf.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu test = new JMenu("Open file");
    test.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {

            JOptionPane jop = new JOptionPane();
            jop.requestFocus();

            //There is a warning, but if you do "JOptionPane.showInputDialog(...)" it doesn't do anything.
            Object input = jop.showInputDialog(jf, "Enter path", "Title", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, null, "");

        }
        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
        }
        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
        }
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
        }
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
        }
    });
    mb.add(test);
    jf.add(mb);

}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The `JMenu` has focus until the mouse is released but the dialog opens on mouse pressed.

Either use `ActionListener` (recommended) or do your logic in mouse released.

---

In any event, taking action on mouse pressed usually has a bad use experience. Users expect that nothing should happen if they move away the mouse from the button while mouse button is down (sort of "pressed by mistake"). [This post](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/9004/when-is-it-a-good-idea-to-perform-actions-on-mouse-down-as-opposed-to-click-mou) goes into more detail of the UX of mouse events.

Comment: I can't use ActionListener, JMenu straight up ignores it and a MenuListener doesn't behave like I want (with multiple items, hovering on an item after clicking on one selects it). Putting the JOptionPane in the main(), and putting `jop.requestFocus()` in `mouseReleased()` doesn't do anything.

Comment: *"doesn't behave like I want"* Seems this GUI is going not to behave as the user wants. A good general rule for GUIs is to follow the 'path of least surprise'.

Comment: @Zezombye You should not be doing anything based on the user’s interaction with a JMenu in the first place.  Add a JMenuItem to your JMenu, and add your ActionListener to that JMenuItem.  Or, even better, [set an Action](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setAction-javax.swing.Action-) on the JMenuItem.

Answer (score 0):

try this i guess it works
**For Double Click**

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0)
{
   if(arg0.getClickCount() == 2)
   {
       // your code to execute
   }
}
```

Similarly you can try For Single Click

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0)
    {
       if(arg0.getClickCount() == 1)
       {
           // your code to execute
       }
    }
```